# Photo album for kiosk presentation

Tags: android, photo-gallery, kiosk-mode, photography, photographic-mosaic

I want to have an android tablet with a photobook into the shop, to show our capabilities and previous made projects. There, customers shall only be possible to navigate through the photobook, i provided them (kiosk mode). The photos itself will come from Google Drive / Google Fotos /Onedrive or can be also saved locally.

It can be an app or also a self hosted website, capabilities for hosting are there ;-)

The customers shall can filter on:

- tags
- employees, who did the project

Very important here is, that it's easy to use and provides a good user experience to the users :-)

Do you have any recommendation which software to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can propose [Fully Kiosk Browser & App Lockdown](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.ozerov.fully&hl=pl&gl=US)

You can lockdown Android tablet easily. It has a lot of configuration options.

I am using this solution with web application in industry and it works preety well.